PGFplots, tables and multiple paths
I'm trying to use \addplot table to read multiple lines from the same file, but I want to be able to identify them as different paths so that I can apply a decoration on each separately.
The result I would like to get is as in
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}}}] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}}}] (0,1) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I first tried this piece of code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{test1.dat}
    x   y
    0   0
    1   0
    
    0   1
    1   1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[x=1cm, y=1cm, axis lines=none]
        \addplot[postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}}}] table[x index=0, y index=1]{test1.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

It breaks the line (as expected) but of course it creates only one path, therefore the arrow's position is wrong.

Then I read this post that addresses quite a similar problem, so I came up with
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrowno{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
            }
        }
    }

\begin{filecontents}{test2.dat}
    n   x   y
    1   0   0
    1   1   0
    
    2   0   1
    2   1   1
\end{filecontents}
%\pgfplotstableread{test2.dat}{\loadedtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[x=1cm, y=1cm, axis lines=none]
        \foreach \i in {1,2} {
            \addplot[postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}}}]
                table[x index=1, y index=2, discard if not={0}{\i}]{test2.dat};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

which works...

... but when I use it on my actual data file (which requires a \foreach), it crashes. Even when I use the (commented above) \pgfplotstableread (and replace "test2.dat" with "\loadedtable" in the \addplot command), there is like 100 different lines (they don't have the same length) and it looks like it's too much :( Not mentionning a bunch of warnings:
NOTE: coordinate (4.095986,4.997566) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in x). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 
Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away) on input line 55.

Any ideas?
[EDIT] As a reply to @hpekristiansen (thanks for the tip about the warning message by the way): here is a sample file; lines consist in a variable number (larger than 2) of points.
[EDIT] I can't paste the whole sample file here (Body is limited to 30000 characters) and I can't figure out another way to share it! It does work for 4 lines, the problem is it crashes when the 21st line is processed (! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].)
n            x               y          
1   -9.989335    -4.781825 
1   -9.820655    -4.802495 
1   -9.651686    -4.823383 
1   -9.482414    -4.844488 
1   -9.312827    -4.865812 
1   -9.142910    -4.887356 
1   -8.972649    -4.909120 
1   -8.802029    -4.931104 
1   -8.631033    -4.953307 
1   -8.459644    -4.975728 
1   -8.287846    -4.998366 

2   8.299526     -4.996822 
2   8.471296     -4.974198 
2   8.642657     -4.951792 
2   8.813627     -4.929604 
2   8.984223     -4.907635 
2   9.154460     -4.885886 
2   9.324354     -4.864357 
2   9.493919     -4.843048 
2   9.663170     -4.821957 
2   9.832119     -4.801085 

3   -9.845163    -4.411595 
3   -9.676839    -4.433043 
3   -9.508222    -4.454733 
3   -9.339297    -4.476670 
3   -9.170052    -4.498853 
3   -9.000471    -4.521285 
3   -8.830538    -4.543968 
3   -8.660236    -4.566903 
3   -8.489549    -4.590089 
3   -8.318457    -4.613528 
3   -8.146940    -4.637218 
3   -7.974979    -4.661159 
3   -7.802552    -4.685348 
3   -7.629636    -4.709782 
3   -7.456208    -4.734458 
3   -7.282241    -4.759371 
3   -7.107711    -4.784515 
3   -6.932589    -4.809881 
3   -6.756846    -4.835461 
3   -6.580454    -4.861244 
3   -6.403380    -4.887216 
3   -6.225591    -4.913363 
3   -6.047055    -4.939667 
3   -5.867737    -4.966108 
3   -5.687599    -4.992662 

4   5.683356     -4.993287 
4   5.863513     -4.966731 
4   6.042851     -4.940287 
4   6.221405     -4.913979 
4   6.399210     -4.887828 
4   6.576301     -4.861852 
4   6.752709     -4.836065 
4   6.928466     -4.810480 
4   7.103603     -4.785108 
4   7.278147     -4.759960 
4   7.452126     -4.735041 
4   7.625567     -4.710359 
4   7.798495     -4.685919 
4   7.970933     -4.661724 
4   8.142905     -4.637778 
4   8.314431     -4.614082 
4   8.485533     -4.590637 
4   8.656230     -4.567445 
4   8.826541     -4.544504 
4   8.996482     -4.521816 
4   9.166071     -4.499377 
4   9.335324     -4.477188 
4   9.504256     -4.455246 
4   9.672880     -4.433550 
4   9.841211     -4.412096 

5   -9.870775    -4.019469 
5   -9.703154    -4.041442 
5   -9.535252    -4.063682 
5   -9.367056    -4.086194 
5   -9.198551    -4.108980 
5   -9.029723    -4.132045 
5   -8.860554    -4.155390 
5   -8.691028    -4.179020 
5   -8.521127    -4.202937 
5   -8.350831    -4.227141 
5   -8.180121    -4.251636 
5   -8.008976    -4.276422 
5   -7.837371    -4.301498 
5   -7.665285    -4.326866 
5   -7.492691    -4.352522 
5   -7.319562    -4.378466 
5   -7.145872    -4.404693 
5   -6.971588    -4.431198 
5   -6.796682    -4.457976 
5   -6.621119    -4.485017 
5   -6.444865    -4.512312 
5   -6.267883    -4.539849 
5   -6.090136    -4.567613 
5   -5.911584    -4.595586 
5   -5.732185    -4.623747 
5   -5.551898    -4.652073 
5   -5.370676    -4.680536 
5   -5.188476    -4.709103 
5   -5.005251    -4.737737 
5   -4.820953    -4.766395 
5   -4.635535    -4.795031 
5   -4.448950    -4.823590 
5   -4.261150    -4.852010 
5   -4.072093    -4.880225 
5   -3.881733    -4.908160 
5   -3.690033    -4.935731 
5   -3.496956    -4.962848 
5   -3.302473    -4.989413 

6   3.270541     -4.993696 
6   3.465256     -4.967232 
6   3.658561     -4.940198 
6   3.850484     -4.912695 
6   4.041060     -4.884814 
6   4.230328     -4.856639 
6   4.418330     -4.828247 
6   4.605111     -4.799707 
6   4.790716     -4.771080 
6   4.975194     -4.742422 
6   5.158592     -4.713781 
6   5.340956     -4.685200 
6   5.522334     -4.656718 
6   5.702772     -4.628368 
6   5.882313     -4.600177 
6   6.061000     -4.572172 
6   6.238876     -4.544373 
6   6.415980     -4.516798 
6   6.592351     -4.489462 
6   6.768024     -4.462379 
6   6.943036     -4.435558 
6   7.117419     -4.409007 
6   7.291205     -4.382735 
6   7.464423     -4.356744 
6   7.637103     -4.331041 
6   7.809270     -4.305626 
6   7.980952     -4.280502 
6   8.152171     -4.255668 
6   8.322950     -4.231126 
6   8.493312     -4.206874 
6   8.663277     -4.182911 
6   8.832863     -4.159234 
6   9.002089     -4.135842 
6   9.170972     -4.112732 
6   9.339529     -4.089900 
6   9.507774     -4.067344 
6   9.675723     -4.045060 
6   9.843389     -4.023044 

7   -9.897404    -3.625998 
7   -9.730542    -3.648451 
7   -9.563416    -3.671196 
7   -9.396011    -3.694238 
7   -9.228313    -3.717582 
7   -9.060308    -3.741232 
7   -8.891979    -3.765194 
7   -8.723308    -3.789472 
7   -8.554278    -3.814071 
7   -8.384870    -3.838994 
7   -8.215062    -3.864246 
7   -8.044833    -3.889829 
7   -7.874160    -3.915748 
7   -7.703018    -3.942002 
7   -7.531380    -3.968595 
7   -7.359219    -3.995527 
7   -7.186505    -4.022797 
7   -7.013207    -4.050404 
7   -6.839291    -4.078345 
7   -6.664721    -4.106615 
7   -6.489460    -4.135208 
7   -6.313469    -4.164116 
7   -6.136705    -4.193327 
7   -5.959124    -4.222829 
7   -5.780679    -4.252603 
7   -5.601321    -4.282630 
7   -5.421001    -4.312886 
7   -5.239663    -4.343341 
7   -5.057253    -4.373961 
7   -4.873714    -4.404706 
7   -4.688988    -4.435531 
7   -4.503016    -4.466382 
7   -4.315738    -4.497197 
7   -4.127094    -4.527908 
7   -3.937027    -4.558436 
7   -3.745482    -4.588693 
7   -3.552405    -4.618580 
7   -3.357751    -4.647989 
7   -3.161478    -4.676799 
7   -2.963555    -4.704881 
7   -2.763961    -4.732094 
7   -2.562688    -4.758287 
7   -2.359742    -4.783301 
7   -2.155147    -4.806972 
7   -1.948946    -4.829129 
7   -1.741203    -4.849601 
7   -1.532003    -4.868218 
7   -1.321457    -4.884816 
7   -1.109696    -4.899238 
7   -0.896875    -4.911344 
7   -0.683169    -4.921009 
7   -0.468772    -4.928131 
7   -0.253890    -4.932631 
7   -0.038744    -4.934461 
7   0.176443     -4.933600 
7   0.391446     -4.930056 
7   0.606042     -4.923871 
7   0.820020     -4.915111 
7   1.033181     -4.903871 
7   1.245342     -4.890267 
7   1.456342     -4.874435 
7   1.666040     -4.856527 
7   1.874319     -4.836703 
7   2.081084     -4.815133 
7   2.286263     -4.791988 
7   2.489806     -4.767438 
7   2.691684     -4.741650 
7   2.891882     -4.714787 
7   3.090405     -4.687002 
7   3.287268     -4.658438 
7   3.482501     -4.629230 
7   3.676141     -4.599502 
7   3.868232     -4.569367 
7   4.058825     -4.538926 
7   4.247974     -4.508271 
7   4.435738     -4.477485 
7   4.622173     -4.446639 
7   4.807341     -4.415799 
7   4.991301     -4.385019 
7   5.174110     -4.354349 
7   5.355828     -4.323830 
7   5.536508     -4.293499 
7   5.716207     -4.263387 
7   5.894974     -4.233519 
7   6.072861     -4.203917 
7   6.249914     -4.174600 
7   6.426179     -4.145581 
7   6.601698     -4.116874 
7   6.776512     -4.088487 
7   6.950659     -4.060426 
7   7.124176     -4.032699 
7   7.297097     -4.005307 
7   7.469453     -3.978253 
7   7.641276     -3.951538 
7   7.812593     -3.925162 
7   7.983432     -3.899123 
7   8.153818     -3.873419 
7   8.323775     -3.848048 
7   8.493325     -3.823007 
7   8.662489     -3.798292 
7   8.831287     -3.773899 
7   8.999737     -3.749824 
7   9.167857     -3.726062 
7   9.335664     -3.702608 
7   9.503172     -3.679458 
7   9.670397     -3.656607 
7   9.837353     -3.634049 

8   -9.924946    -3.231065 
8   -9.758897    -3.253949 
8   -9.592602    -3.277147 
8   -9.426047    -3.300666 
8   -9.259220    -3.324511 
8   -9.092106    -3.348691 
8   -8.924688    -3.373212 
8   -8.756949    -3.398079 
8   -8.588873    -3.423300 
8   -8.420438    -3.448881 
8   -8.251626    -3.474828 
8   -8.082414    -3.501147 
8   -7.912778    -3.527844 
8   -7.742694    -3.554923 
8   -7.572134    -3.582389 
8   -7.401071    -3.610247 
8   -7.229473    -3.638499 
8   -7.057308    -3.667147 
8   -6.884541    -3.696193 
8   -6.711134    -3.725636 
8   -6.537048    -3.755475 
8   -6.362239    -3.785706 
8   -6.186664    -3.816322 
8   -6.010272    -3.847315 
8   -5.833014    -3.878674 
8   -5.654834    -3.910384 
8   -5.475675    -3.942425 
8   -5.295476    -3.974774 
8   -5.114173    -4.007402 
8   -4.931699    -4.040273 
8   -4.747985    -4.073346 
8   -4.562958    -4.106571 
8   -4.376545    -4.139889 
8   -4.188669    -4.173233 
8   -3.999256    -4.206523 
8   -3.808230    -4.239669 
8   -3.615519    -4.272567 
8   -3.421052    -4.305100 
8   -3.224768    -4.337137 
8   -3.026609    -4.368532 
8   -2.826533    -4.399124 
8   -2.624508    -4.428738 
8   -2.420520    -4.457186 
8   -2.214576    -4.484266 
8   -2.006705    -4.509771 
8   -1.796962    -4.533483 
8   -1.585434    -4.555187 
8   -1.372234    -4.574666 
8   -1.157512    -4.591717 
8   -0.941444    -4.606149 
8   -0.724239    -4.617791 
8   -0.506133    -4.626501 
8   -0.287381    -4.632170 
8   -0.068258    -4.634724 
8   0.150955     -4.634129 
8   0.369971     -4.630394 
8   0.588510     -4.623567 
8   0.806306     -4.613736 
8   1.023108     -4.601023 
8   1.238691     -4.585582 
8   1.452858     -4.567592 
8   1.665443     -4.547248 
8   1.876309     -4.524761 
8   2.085354     -4.500347 
8   2.292504     -4.474223 
8   2.497712     -4.446602 
8   2.700959     -4.417692 
8   2.902246     -4.387687 
8   3.101594     -4.356772 
8   3.299040     -4.325117 
8   3.494631     -4.292877 
8   3.688428     -4.260191 
8   3.880495     -4.227187 
8   4.070904     -4.193975 
8   4.259728     -4.160655 
8   4.447043     -4.127312 
8   4.632924     -4.094021 
8   4.817447     -4.060847 
8   5.000685     -4.027845 
8   5.182709     -3.995061 
8   5.363587     -3.962535 
8   5.543387     -3.930299 
8   5.722170     -3.898380 
8   5.899995     -3.866801 
8   6.076920     -3.835578 
8   6.252998     -3.804726 
8   6.428279     -3.774255 
8   6.602810     -3.744171 
8   6.776635     -3.714481 
8   6.949796     -3.685188 
8   7.122332     -3.656292 
8   7.294279     -3.627793 
8   7.465671     -3.599691 
8   7.636541     -3.571981 
8   7.806918     -3.544661 
8   7.976830     -3.517727 
8   8.146303     -3.491174 
8   8.315362     -3.464996 
8   8.484029     -3.439187 
8   8.652326     -3.413743 
8   8.820273     -3.388656 
8   8.987888     -3.363920 
8   9.155190     -3.339529 
8   9.322194     -3.315476 
8   9.488917     -3.291754 
8   9.655371     -3.268358 
8   9.821572     -3.245279 
8   9.987532     -3.222512 

9   -9.953282    -2.834570 
9   -9.788093    -2.857826 
9   -9.622679    -2.881416 
9   -9.457030    -2.905349 
9   -9.291132    -2.929633 
9   -9.124970    -2.954276 
9   -8.958530    -2.979287 
9   -8.791796    -3.004674 
9   -8.624749    -3.030445 
9   -8.457371    -3.056609 
9   -8.289642    -3.083176 
9   -8.121541    -3.110153 
9   -7.953044    -3.137548 
9   -7.784127    -3.165370 
9   -7.614764    -3.193627 
9   -7.444924    -3.222327 
9   -7.274578    -3.251476 
9   -7.103693    -3.281080 
9   -6.932232    -3.311146 
9   -6.760158    -3.341678 
9   -6.587429    -3.372679 
9   -6.414000    -3.404151 
9   -6.239824    -3.436094 
9   -6.064850    -3.468506 
9   -5.889022    -3.501381 
9   -5.712281    -3.534711 
9   -5.534565    -3.568485 
9   -5.355805    -3.602687 
9   -5.175930    -3.637294 
9   -4.994863    -3.672279 
9   -4.812523    -3.707608 
9   -4.628825    -3.743238 
9   -4.443680    -3.779116 
9   -4.256995    -3.815180 
9   -4.068676    -3.851354 
9   -3.878623    -3.887549 
9   -3.686741    -3.923663 
9   -3.492933    -3.959573 
9   -3.297106    -3.995141 
9   -3.099174    -4.030208 
9   -2.899060    -4.064596 
9   -2.696702    -4.098105 
9   -2.492053    -4.130516 
9   -2.285090    -4.161589 
9   -2.075819    -4.191068 
9   -1.864275    -4.218685 
9   -1.650532    -4.244163 
9   -1.434704    -4.267223 
9   -1.216949    -4.287591 
9   -0.997467    -4.305009 
9   -0.776503    -4.319242 
9   -0.554341    -4.330089 
9   -0.331299    -4.337389 
9   -0.107720    -4.341033 
9   0.116034     -4.340964 
9   0.339599     -4.337183 
9   0.562614     -4.329748 
9   0.784737     -4.318773 
9   1.005651     -4.304417 
9   1.225073     -4.286885 
9   1.442760     -4.266412 
9   1.658513     -4.243258 
9   1.872176     -4.217696 
9   2.083636     -4.190004 
9   2.292822     -4.160461 
9   2.499699     -4.129334 
9   2.704262     -4.096878 
9   2.906536     -4.063333 
9   3.106568     -4.028916 
9   3.304420     -3.993827 
9   3.500171     -3.958244 
9   3.693906     -3.922324 
9   3.885718     -3.886205 
9   4.075704     -3.850008 
9   4.263961     -3.813837 
9   4.450587     -3.777779 
9   4.635677     -3.741909 
9   4.819322     -3.706290 
9   5.001613     -3.670973 
9   5.182635     -3.636001 
9   5.362467     -3.601408 
9   5.541187     -3.567223 
9   5.718866     -3.533465 
9   5.895572     -3.500151 
9   6.071367     -3.467293 
9   6.246311     -3.434899 
9   6.420458     -3.402973 
9   6.593860     -3.371519 
9   6.766564     -3.340535 
9   6.938615     -3.310021 
9   7.110053     -3.279972 
9   7.280918     -3.250384 
9   7.451244     -3.221252 
9   7.621065     -3.192569 
9   7.790412     -3.164329 
9   7.959313     -3.136522 
9   8.127794     -3.109143 
9   8.295881     -3.082181 
9   8.463597     -3.055630 
9   8.630962     -3.029480 
9   8.797997     -3.003723 
9   8.964721     -2.978351 
9   9.131150     -2.953354 
9   9.297301     -2.928724 
9   9.463190     -2.904454 
9   9.628830     -2.880533 
9   9.794235     -2.856956 
9   9.959417     -2.833712 

10  -9.982276    -2.436423 
10  -9.817987    -2.459985 
10  -9.653500    -2.483900 
10  -9.488804    -2.508178 
10  -9.323886    -2.532827 
10  -9.158733    -2.557859 
10  -8.993330    -2.583281 
10  -8.827663    -2.609107 
10  -8.661714    -2.635344 
10  -8.495467    -2.662005 
10  -8.328902    -2.689101 
10  -8.161998    -2.716642 
10  -7.994734    -2.744640 
10  -7.827086    -2.773106 
10  -7.659027    -2.802052 
10  -7.490530    -2.831488 
10  -7.321564    -2.861426 
10  -7.152097    -2.891876 
10  -6.982094    -2.922849 
10  -6.811516    -2.954354 
10  -6.640321    -2.986401 
10  -6.468465    -3.018997 
10  -6.295899    -3.052149 
10  -6.122569    -3.085863 
10  -5.948419    -3.120139 
10  -5.773386    -3.154980 
10  -5.597402    -3.190381 
10  -5.420396    -3.226336 
10  -5.242289    -3.262833 
10  -5.062996    -3.299856 
10  -4.882427    -3.337380 
10  -4.700484    -3.375373 
10  -4.517064    -3.413794 
10  -4.332056    -3.452590 
10  -4.145346    -3.491696 
10  -3.956812    -3.531030 
10  -3.766330    -3.570495 
10  -3.573772    -3.609973 
10  -3.379010    -3.649325 
10  -3.181920    -3.688384 
10  -2.982384    -3.726962 
10  -2.780293    -3.764838 
10  -2.575557    -3.801764 
10  -2.368108    -3.837461 
10  -2.157907    -3.871624 
10  -1.944955    -3.903923 
10  -1.729295    -3.934008 
10  -1.511026    -3.961518 
10  -1.290301    -3.986089 
10  -1.067339    -4.007369 
10  -0.842418    -4.025029 
10  -0.615877    -4.038780 
10  -0.388109    -4.048386 
10  -0.159547    -4.053674 
10  0.069345     -4.054548 
10  0.298093     -4.050993 
10  0.526228     -4.043072 
10  0.753302     -4.030930 
10  0.978905     -4.014779 
10  1.202676     -3.994888 
10  1.424312     -3.971573 
10  1.643571     -3.945179 
10  1.860274     -3.916065 
10  2.074301     -3.884596 
10  2.285589     -3.851127 
10  2.494120     -3.815996 
10  2.699919     -3.779520 
10  2.903042     -3.741987 
10  3.103573     -3.703659 
10  3.301614     -3.664764 
10  3.497279     -3.625507 
10  3.690690     -3.586061 
10  3.881975     -3.546576 
10  4.071262     -3.507177 
10  4.258676     -3.467971 
10  4.444341     -3.429044 
10  4.628373     -3.390468 
10  4.810886     -3.352301 
10  4.991985     -3.314588 
10  5.171769     -3.277364 
10  5.350333     -3.240657 
10  5.527764     -3.204487 
10  5.704141     -3.168866 
10  5.879540     -3.133804 
10  6.054031     -3.099305 
10  6.227677     -3.065370 
10  6.400538     -3.031997 
10  6.572668     -2.999183 
10  6.744117     -2.966920 
10  6.914933     -2.935202 
10  7.085158     -2.904021 
10  7.254832     -2.873366 
10  7.423991     -2.843227 
10  7.592669     -2.813595 
10  7.760897     -2.784457 
10  7.928705     -2.755803 
10  8.096117     -2.727622 
10  8.263160     -2.699902 
10  8.429856     -2.672632 
10  8.596226     -2.645801 
10  8.762290     -2.619398 
10  8.928067     -2.593412 
10  9.093572     -2.567831 
10  9.258821     -2.542647 
10  9.423831     -2.517848 
10  9.588613     -2.493425 
10  9.753181     -2.469368 
10  9.917546     -2.445668 

11  -9.848424    -2.060349 
11  -9.684901    -2.084515 
11  -9.521197    -2.109061 
11  -9.357302    -2.133996 
11  -9.193203    -2.159332 
11  -9.028888    -2.185080 
11  -8.864342    -2.211253 
11  -8.699551    -2.237862 
11  -8.534498    -2.264921 
11  -8.369165    -2.292444 
11  -8.203534    -2.320442 
11  -8.037584    -2.348931 
11  -7.871293    -2.377925 
11  -7.704635    -2.407438 
11  -7.537586    -2.437485 
11  -7.370116    -2.468080 
11  -7.202193    -2.499240 
11  -7.033785    -2.530980 
11  -6.864853    -2.563313 
11  -6.695358    -2.596256 
11  -6.525255    -2.629822 
11  -6.354496    -2.664025 
11  -6.183028    -2.698878 
11  -6.010793    -2.734392 
11  -5.837729    -2.770577 
11  -5.663766    -2.807439 
11  -5.488828    -2.844984 
11  -5.312835    -2.883211 
11  -5.135694    -2.922117 
11  -4.957309    -2.961691 
11  -4.777574    -3.001917 
11  -4.596371    -3.042768 
11  -4.413577    -3.084208 
11  -4.229056    -3.126186 
11  -4.042666    -3.168639 
11  -3.854254    -3.211482 
11  -3.663659    -3.254611 
11  -3.470716    -3.297894 
11  -3.275255    -3.341173 
11  -3.077106    -3.384256 
11  -2.876107    -3.426913 
11  -2.672104    -3.468877 
11  -2.464965    -3.509836 
11  -2.254586    -3.549437 
11  -2.040904    -3.587284 
11  -1.823907    -3.622947 
11  -1.603649    -3.655963 
11  -1.380257    -3.685855 
11  -1.153946    -3.712143 
11  -0.925018    -3.734365 
11  -0.693867    -3.752102 
11  -0.460967    -3.764994 
11  -0.226867    -3.772771 
11  0.007836     -3.775264 
11  0.242518     -3.772416 
11  0.476556     -3.764291 
11  0.709355     -3.751065 
11  0.940372     -3.733017 
11  1.169137     -3.710510 
11  1.395262     -3.683967 
11  1.618449     -3.653851 
11  1.838493     -3.620644 
11  2.055269     -3.584821 
11  2.268730     -3.546843 
11  2.478890     -3.507140 
11  2.685817     -3.466104 
11  2.889615     -3.424085 
11  3.090419     -3.381391 
11  3.288383     -3.338288 
11  3.483670     -3.295003 
11  3.676452     -3.251725 
11  3.866895     -3.208612 
11  4.055168     -3.165792 
11  4.241429     -3.123369 
11  4.425829     -3.081424 
11  4.608513     -3.040023 
11  4.789614     -2.999212 
11  4.969257     -2.959030 
11  5.147555     -2.919499 
11  5.324616     -2.880638 
11  5.500537     -2.842457 
11  5.675406     -2.804958 
11  5.849307     -2.768140 
11  6.022314     -2.732001 
11  6.194496     -2.696531 
11  6.365915     -2.661722 
11  6.536628     -2.627562 
11  6.706689     -2.594038 
11  6.876146     -2.561136 
11  7.045041     -2.528843 
11  7.213416     -2.497143 
11  7.381307     -2.466021 
11  7.548748     -2.435462 
11  7.715771     -2.405451 
11  7.882403     -2.375974 
11  8.048671     -2.347014 
11  8.214599     -2.318558 
11  8.380210     -2.290592 
11  8.545523     -2.263101 
11  8.710558     -2.236072 
11  8.875332     -2.209492 
11  9.039862     -2.183348 
11  9.204163     -2.157628 
11  9.368247     -2.132319 
11  9.532129     -2.107411 
11  9.695821     -2.082891 
11  9.859332     -2.058749 

12  -9.879235    -1.658858 
12  -9.716703    -1.683198 
12  -9.554022    -1.707929 
12  -9.391183    -1.733064 
12  -9.228175    -1.758614 
12  -9.064986    -1.784593 
12  -8.901604    -1.811015 
12  -8.738016    -1.837893 
12  -8.574208    -1.865242 
12  -8.410163    -1.893077 
12  -8.245865    -1.921414 
12  -8.081296    -1.950269 
12  -7.916434    -1.979659 
12  -7.751258    -2.009602 
12  -7.585744    -2.040115 
12  -7.419865    -2.071218 
12  -7.253593    -2.102929 
12  -7.086897    -2.135269 
12  -6.919742    -2.168256 
12  -6.752089    -2.201913 
12  -6.583897    -2.236259 
12  -6.415121    -2.271315 
12  -6.245709    -2.307102 
12  -6.075606    -2.343640 
12  -5.904751    -2.380948 
12  -5.733074    -2.419044 
12  -5.560503    -2.457944 
12  -5.386952    -2.497664 
12  -5.212331    -2.538213 
12  -5.036539    -2.579598 
12  -4.859464    -2.621820 
12  -4.680982    -2.664873 
12  -4.500958    -2.708741 
12  -4.319244    -2.753397 
12  -4.135677    -2.798800 
12  -3.950081    -2.844892 
12  -3.762265    -2.891591 
12  -3.572024    -2.938790 
12  -3.379143    -2.986350 
12  -3.183397    -3.034095 
12  -2.984556    -3.081806 
12  -2.782392    -3.129210 
12  -2.576687    -3.175983 
12  -2.367246    -3.221736 
12  -2.153908    -3.266019 
12  -1.936566    -3.308318 
12  -1.715187    -3.348063 
12  -1.489829    -3.384636 
12  -1.260660    -3.417395 
12  -1.027975    -3.445695 
12  -0.792203    -3.468923 
12  -0.553902    -3.486534 
12  -0.313750    -3.498088 
12  -0.072520    -3.503285 
12  0.168964     -3.501984 
12  0.409861     -3.494222 
12  0.649361     -3.480203 
12  0.886727     -3.460289 
12  1.121326     -3.434965 
12  1.352650     -3.404808 
12  1.580325     -3.370447 
12  1.804107     -3.332531 
12  2.023874     -3.291694 
12  2.239608     -3.248537 
12  2.451373     -3.203608 
12  2.659301     -3.157397 
12  2.863566     -3.110329 
12  3.064376     -3.062767 
12  3.261952     -3.015013 
12  3.456526     -2.967318 
12  3.648326     -2.919883 
12  3.837573     -2.872869 
12  4.024479     -2.826401 
12  4.209242     -2.780576 
12  4.392048     -2.735465 
12  4.573069     -2.691120 
12  4.752459     -2.647575 
12  4.930364     -2.604853 
12  5.106912     -2.562965 
12  5.282224     -2.521914 
12  5.456405     -2.481698 
12  5.629554     -2.442307 
12  5.801759     -2.403729 
12  5.973099     -2.365950 
12  6.143646     -2.328952 
12  6.313466     -2.292717 
12  6.482617     -2.257225 
12  6.651154     -2.222455 
12  6.819125     -2.188386 
12  6.986575     -2.154999 
12  7.153542     -2.122273 
12  7.320065     -2.090187 
12  7.486176     -2.058721 
12  7.651906     -2.027856 
12  7.817282     -1.997573 
12  7.982329     -1.967853 
12  8.147072     -1.938679 
12  8.311531     -1.910033 
12  8.475726     -1.881898 
12  8.639674     -1.854259 
12  8.803392     -1.827100 
12  8.966896     -1.800406 
12  9.130199     -1.774163 
12  9.293315     -1.748356 
12  9.456254     -1.722974 
12  9.619029     -1.698002 
12  9.781649     -1.673428 
12  9.944123     -1.649242 


Welcome to tex.sx.

What your code does is to throw away point that does not meet the test(not the same line). If you do not want to see the warnings you can use filter discard warning=false. Are all your lines given by two points? (Then there might be an other way). As it is now, your question is not answerable, as it works with the data given but does not with the real secret data. Please edit the question to include a small subsection of the real data. -enough to show the error.

I just tried it with the new data - I get four lines with arrows. -so it is still working! Do you not get that? Please figure out where it breaks. You could delete your question or edit it to ask about something that does not work.

better to edit this question than delete and ask another. if you delete questions, you can trigger a question ban. (I don't think it would do this for a single question, but I think it is more sensitive if you are newer to the site. once you have a history on the site, you can delete with greater impunity.)

@cfr: You are right that deletion is bad, but what else to do? I do genuinely not know what best practice/rules there are. If everything just works, then there is no basis left for this question. Is it better if OP waits for us to close the question?

@hpekristiansen  I meant it would be better to edit it so it doesn't work rather than deleting and asking a new question (which I know the system doesn't like). this was for the OP since nobody else can edit it to produce a meaningful question.

Voting to close as the problem can not be reproduced
